# Is there a way to set Height to a Drawer Header?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking for a way to set the height to a Drawer Header.
I have this DrawerHeader:

```dart
DrawerHeader(
  child: Text('Categories', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  )
)
```

But I don't see a way to set the Height to the Drawer, that's too big.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You wrap this with a `SizedBox` widget.

```dart
const SizedBox(
   height: 64.0,
   child: DrawerHeader(
       child: Text('Categories', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
       margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Great, it works.
Do you know which metrics are used in height? I set it to 80.0 to make it visible and with the AppBar height.

Comment: If you look at the source code the standard height is set to `_kDrawerHeaderHeight = 160.0 + 1.0` plus the status bar height. (At least in the current v1.16.3)

Comment: flutter analyze suggests using a SizedBox instead of a Container.

Comment: yeah, you are right, this answer was posted in 2018. Updated

Answer (score 25):

You can use **SizedBox** widget for resize height **DrawerHeader**

```dart
new SizedBox(
   height : 120.0, 
   child  : new DrawerHeader(
      child  : new Text('Categories', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
      margin : EdgeInsets.zero,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use SizedBox.

A Container is a heavier Widget than a SizedBox, and as bonus, SizedBox has a const constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answers, I would put my `Drawer` in a `SizedBox`. Since it is also important for me to controll where the `Drawer` appears, which by default should be the `centerLeft`, I would make the child of the box an `Align` with an  `alignment =  Alignment.topLeft`. See example below.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 300,//Your height goes here
    child: Drawer(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, //Your background color goes here.
      child: ListView(
        children: [ ... ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```